# The glowing effect around WPF textbox is not visible enough

Tags: wpf, effects

I am using following style to have a glowing effect around the textbox...But even if I increase width of BlurRadius, it is not increasing the area that glows.

```
 <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Effect">
                      <Setter.Value>
                         <DropShadowEffect  Opacity="1" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Red" BlurRadius="10" />
                      </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>                     
              </Trigger>                                                              
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

EDIT :
**Textbox**

```
<TextBox
                                                    x:Name="a"
                                                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                                    MaxLength="11"
                                                    Height="20"
                                                    Width="67"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"                                                    
                                                    utils:InputMasking.Mask="^((\d{0,7})|(\d{0,7}\.\d{0,3}))$">
                                                    <TextBox.Text>
                                                        <Binding Path="abc.Value" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" />
                                                    </TextBox.Text>                                                   

                                                </TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me just fine. Can you give us the XAML for the textbox?

Comment: am also able to see the glow...but it is very very small...

Comment: It's subtle. Try a much larger number like 100.

Comment: do u mean shadow depth? When I apply shadow depth as 100 i can see the shadow much below

Comment: I changed the values as below...and it is working now..thanksss. I dont  knwo it was not working before...Anyway thanks alot.<DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="0" Color="Blue"  BlurRadius="50" />

Comment: if u can give me answer as comment..i can select as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was the answer, I will restate it:

Increase the BlurRadius to a much larger number since the change is subtle. Going from 1 to 2 won't be noticeable, but 1 to 50 will be.